# Warning message of deprecated link option of Docker

Tags: docker

I try to link a wordpress container to a mysql container with following command and get the output of warning about deprecated option of `-link`.

```
$ sudo docker -v
Docker version 0.9.0, build 2b3fdf2
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
3987ba6ef34e        p-baleine/mysql:latest   /run.sh             22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:49153->3306/tcp   sad_euclid          
$ sudo docker run -e="DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD" -link sad_euclid:db -d -p 80 p-baleine/wordpress /run.sh
Warning: '-link' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
```

I cannot find any information of deprecation of the link option.

Why the link option is deprecated and what is the alternative of this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check usage and I understand that options should be specified by prefixed double hyphen.

```
$ sudo docker run -e="DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD" --link sad_euclid:db -d -p 80 p-baleine/wordpress /run.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`--link` is deprecated as well.

Basically, links are no longer needed because their main purpose, making container reachable by another by adding environment variable, can be achieved by adding them in the same network. Also, linking containers one by one is very inefficient and may breach network isolation.

When containers are placed in the same network, they are reachable by each other using their container name and other alias as host.

```
docker network create mynet
docker run -d --net mynet --name container1 my_image
docker run -it --net mynet --name container1 another_image
```

Answer (score 0):

3 years ago and it's still possible to use --link

But have a look to the Docker docu and you will find the same notice about a deprecated link option:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/
(the red discreet infobox at the top)